# Neither ASCII or UTF8 can decode French characters, what should I do?

Tags: c#, character-encoding, ascii, diacritics, utf

I have the following function:

```
private void ReceivedData(byte[] data)
{
    string info = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
```

When I use this, then the data, containing an `é` character, replace that character by a question mark (`?`).

For your information, the `data` looks as follows in Visual Studio's Watch window (the mentioned character is found back in `data[27]` and `data[28]`):

[image]

For your information: when I type <kbd>ALT+0233</kbd> on my computer, I see the mentioned `é` character.

When I replace ASCII encoding by UTF8 encoding (as suggested on some websites or some answers here on the site), I get some weird characters, containing question marks (`��`, or in an image [image]):

```
private void ReceivedData(byte[] data)
{
    string info = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
```

Which encoding should I use for correctly decode French characters?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are _decoding_ data using this method. Both methods expect the input data to be in the given format. What format is your `data` in? Did you get it from a file or from somewhere else?

Comment: What encoding was used to produce the byte[] in the first place?

Comment: prolly you should use  CP(Windows)-1252 encoding ... ASCII doesn't have "French characters" ... UTF8 use 2 bytes for them

Comment: Could you provide an *example* of `data` array, please? There are many possible encoding to choose from, let's have a look at the `data`. To get a readable example: `Console.Write(string.Join(" ", data));`

Comment: try `Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data)`

Comment: Unicode use always at least 2 bytes for character ... so if data doesnt have mostly 0 on every second byte then unicode would not work

Comment: ... yeap ... it's 1252 ... `System.Text.Encoding` has static `GetEncoding` method ...

Comment: I just used `Unicode` and it looks like Chinese: `湜潂摯捳慨彰敔畲彧簸湥湟杯滩湼浵敭彲牤敩籼�` :-)

Comment: @Selvin: how can I use this 1251 or 1252 encoding?

Comment: @Dominique then use `Encoding.Latin1.GetString(data)`

Comment: @PMF: In the meantime I know that Latin1 or Windows(1252) encoding both solve my issue but still I wonder: how can I know which encoding a computer is using (I'm sending messages over TCP sockets, that's the background)?

Comment: @Dominique: When got unfamiliar encoding you can try quering all available encodings and inspect the results (please, have a look at my edit)

Comment: @Dominique Unless you test it (manually, typically) you don't know. You have to ask whoever sends you the data in what format it is. Some file formats (like plain text files, but also HTML) may specify the encoding in the header. If the file format is not specified or the specification is wrong, you are in trouble. That's why people get this wrong all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a [Win-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) encoding (which is for various Latin characters with diacritics),

```
// In case you work with .Net Core you have to enable code pages (1252)
Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);

byte[] data = {
  95, 233, 233, 110
};

var result = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(data);

Console.Write(result);
```

Output:

```
_één
```

**Edit:** In *general case*, when facing *unknown encoding* you can try *quering* all the encodings available and *inspect* the results:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

...

// Enable code pages for .net core
Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);

byte[] data = {
  95, 233, 233, 110
};

var report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Encoding
  .GetEncodings()
  .OrderBy(encoder => encoder.Name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
  .Select(encoder => (name: encoder.Name, text: encoder.GetEncoding().GetString(data)))
  .Where(pair => pair.text.Contains('é')) // at least one é must be present
  .Select(pair => $"{pair.name,-30} : {pair.text}"));

Console.Write(report);
```

Output:

```
iso-8859-1                     : _één
iso-8859-13                    : _één
iso-8859-15                    : _één
iso-8859-2                     : _één
iso-8859-3                     : _één
iso-8859-4                     : _één
iso-8859-9                     : _één
windows-1250                   : _één
windows-1252                   : _één <- The most probabale (IMHO) encoding
windows-1254                   : _één
windows-1256                   : _één
windows-1257                   : _één
windows-1258                   : _één
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. In the meantime I've found this very bizarre French sentence, containing all French accents, and using Windows(1252), I've managed to read even that: Dès Noël où un zéphyr haï me vêt de glaçons würmiens je dîne d’exquis rôtis de bœuf au kir à l’aÿ d’âge mûr & cætera :-)

Comment: I think it's worth to note that the try-all approach only works if you know the expected result. This can't be done automatically, e.g. if the input is really unknown.

Comment: @PMF: or at least when we can distinguish "probable" and "improbable" texts. Please note, that we have `13` candidates for `95, 233, 233, 110` to choose from.

Answer (score 1):

```cs
Encoding.Latin1.GetString(data);
```